# How do you identify a song in a TV score?

Tags: soundtrack, rescue-me

Specifically I'm trying to track down the song playing at the end of *Rescue Me*, Season 4, Episode 6.

A friend was asking me about this. Naturally I assumed with a few Google searches I'd be able to turn it up, but this has been astonishingly difficult.

- Nothing on FX's site seems pertinent.
- Wikipedia turns up nothing.
- The series' official soundtrack was released before Season 4 was released, so no good there
- Turning on subtitles on Netflix *does* reveal the songs lyrics, which is particularly interesting given how muffled they are. I don't know how this data works - obviously in, e.g., in a pirated series, the subtitles may be made by the pirates themselves. But I know nothing of this metadata or whether it might be possible to purchase the episode in a digital form and find other metadata residing with the song.
- The credits on Netflix seem irrelevant. This surprised me because I thought the song would require, you know, being credited. The series is 5-10 years old so may predate modern business models, in which it's clearly *not* to the advantage of the producer to obscure the origin of the song (conversely here I am advertising the series, but I'm guessing this is not the thinking, even if it arguably should be). Some producers involved in sound and music were listed. I could possibly try them on LinkedIn but that sounds like beyond a last resort.
- Shazam was not able to determine it on a few tries.

I feel this information should be somehow researchable / trackable. And obviously it is via social networking but that sounds like a very uphill battle. In particular I'm wondering if it's possible to infer the song from the same metadata that has the subtitles. Are there any other approaches to doing this?

Comment: If there are portions without dialog in between you can use any number of song finding apps out there. http://evolver.fm/2013/04/12/best-app-for-identifying-music-shazam-soundhound-or-musixmatch/

Comment: If Shazam failed to identify, maybe SoundHound will find it... The nice thing about SoundHound is one can find songs by humming the song or typing/speaking the lyrics.

Comment: If you can hear and identify the lyrics, a quick google search should net you the song.  Also,  for future reference, there are sites like [TuneFind.com](http://www.tunefind.com/) that are there specifically to catalogue music used in TV shows (and movies).  All that said, its seems  people have been trying to track down that song for a long time (looking at Google) and it still remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

According to [tv.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/rescue-me/balance-1043588/), the song featured in season 4 episode 6 ("Balance") is [Tell Me What You want](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLJAX_cjUZM), by **Black Hollies**.  Was that the song you heard?  If not, could you post the lyrics?

I found the name of the episode on IMDB.  I entered

> "Rescue Me" Balance Song

in Google, and got the tv.com link.

Comment: Nope, definitely not that. Will post lyrics tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was "How do you identify a song..." In this case, I watched the episode (both on Netflix and Amazon - only Netflix had subtitles). I entered a few lines of the lyrics to search engines and evaluated the results. A few places claimed to have the mp3, but didn't actually. People on a few web forums were trying to identify the same song. One of them (allthelyrics, linked below) had a poster that referred to an episode guide on FX's site. That episode guide no longer lists the music played in the episode, so the forum reference was useful.

The song at the end of Episode 406 (that begins when Dennis Leary is sitting in his truck) has the lyrics posted below. Several [places](http://www.allthelyrics.com/forum/identify-it/59289-rescue-me-season-4-episode-6-closing-credits.html) say that it is *Wedding Song* by Abel (sometimes listed as Able). I haven't been able to find the name of the album or any collection where it might be found. Also, can't find a definitive artist by that name. There is a band called Abel, but their earliest album is from 2009 but the episode in question was broadcast in 2007, so I don't *think* it is the same artist.

The lyrics are distorted, as if through a megaphone, so even by listening, it might be hard to pinpoint the exact artist unless the same technique is used on another song or you actually find the song in question.

> Put on your weddin' dress,
>
> Put on your weddin' dress
>
> I wanna see you
>
> The way I saw you then
>
> Get out your high-heeled shoes
>
> Get out your high-heeled shoes
>
> I wanna watch you walk
>
> In 'em once again
>
> Get out your dress, baby
>
> Get out your dress and shoes
>
> Look at the the big, black sky
>
> Look at the big, black sky